# JetPack Infinite Scroll not working on custom theme

Tags: posts, pagination, plugin-jetpack, add-theme-support

I have a custom theme where I've tried to integrate the Infinite Scroll option within JetPack. Per [this article](http://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/), I've added the following code to functions.php (in addition to activating the module) -

```
<?php 
    add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(         
    'container' => 'content',         
    'footer' => 'page',       
) );
?>
```

The live site can be found [here](http://veblenhigh.com).

My problem is that the infinite scroll function doesn't seem to be, well, functioning. Pagination still occurs when 10 posts are reached.

I'm not exactly sure where I've gone wrong as I followed the articles steps as they were written. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding `'type' => 'click'` under `'footer' => 'page',` to see if the Jetpack works with click rather than the default scroll?

It is also worth going to Settings -> Reading in the admin panel... does it say "To infinity and beyond....We've disabled this option for you since you have footer widgets in Appearance → Widgets, or because your theme does not support infinite scroll."? You might look at what it says here before trying the above step. If you get this error it might be a conflict between your footer and the scroll.

I think your container might also need to be `'blog'` and not `'content'`, as the div your posts are held in seems to be `#blog`.

Comment: Changed the container to `'blog'`, thank you for spotting that.

Adding `'type' => 'click'` generated the "Older Posts" button, however that button did nothing - clicked, spinning 'loading' wheel, then nothing.

In the admin panel, Settings > Reading > Blog pages show at most still shows 10.. which I'm assuming means that there is indeed a conflict. What might this conflict be?

Comment: If you right click on your page and Inspect Element in Chrome/Firefox, you'll see that when you click on the button, a new div is being added each time - with the class `.infinite-view-2`, `.infinite-view-2` etc... Normally there would be posts appearing inside those divs, however currently there is some javascript inside each which starts with `var disqus_shortname = 'veblenhigh';`, does this mean anything to you?

Comment: Are you using a plugin called Disqus? Try disabling it and see if the Infinite scroll works then. I think this might be a similar problem to what you're having, although it's for an unrelated issue: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/disqus-plugin-adding-code-to-json-api-feed

Comment: I am using the Disqus plugin; after disabling the plugin and clearing the cache I've noticed no changes to the site/scrolling.

Comment: ETA - following the directions on the linked WP Support thread resulted in no noticeable changes.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you having trouble with this, it is because there is no render function. Add the following to your functions.php file:

```
add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'container'      => 'blogroll', 
    'footer'         => false,
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'type'           => 'click',
    'render'         => 'wb_infinite_scroll_render',
) );

function wb_infinite_scroll_render() {
    get_template_part( 'templates/content-post', 'standard' );
}
```

Change the name of the container to the name of the container you want the posts to populate in.

Also -- I have a folder named "templates" in my theme with a *content-post-standard.php* file within there that allows me to print out everything I need.

Hope this helps!